# How do I grant an external vendor developer development access

Tags: sandbox, access, grant-login-access

I want to engage a vendor for developments on our SF site. Unfortunately, I'm somewhat of a newbie to SF and am thrown into the deep end of managing a vendor, while we don't have SF admin (yet). I'm on the hunt for an admin, but need to get the development going.

The vendor told me they need Salesforce org credentials, which I think provides them with access to our SF instance. I assume they need access to the sandbox and production.

We have quite sensitive data on our system, so I'm a bit wary of given full access.

How do I give a vendor access to SF, so that they can develop the solution that I'm after, while not jeopardising the integrity of our system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typical standard arrangements, third-party developers are never given direct access to production. Instead, create a new Developer or Developer Pro sandbox for them (this will have no data, but your full configuration), then give them a user in this org. From there, you can migrate (most) changes via Change Sets, and does not require them to log in to your production org at all. This is generally a good idea anyways, as admins should not be making changes in Production directly, but should develop in a separate sandbox or a code repository, with changes only going in to production once they've been tested/vetted.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I definitely want them to develop in a dev environment first before deployment so that we can QA. A few questions: 1) Given my newbie level, can you give me a pointer or an idea how I would go about creating a Developer or Developer Pro sandbox for them? 2) I assume that once that's created I can use the admin credentials to create a user for the sandbox, right? 3) How do I migrate the Change Sets once the dev is done? 4) Can I create randomised test data for the developer to test against? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: @AlexIxeras (1) Setup/Deploy/Sandboxes. You'll see the option while creating the sandbox, assuming you have permission. If not, get with the user that has admin privileges. (2) Yes, you can log in to create a new user for them. Do not reuse existing users. If you need a free license, deactivate an existing non-admin. (3) First, you have to authorize change sets in Deploy/Deployment Settings, then they upload the change set, then you install them via Deploy/Incoming Change Sets. (4) By default, no, but there are third-party vendors like AutoRabit that can do this.

Comment: Thanks. Re (2), do I need to give the vendor user account special rights? I guess admin privileges would be insecure and overkill. Re (3) Is there anywhere where I can test the development in the sandbox prior to deployment to prod? I guess I just go to the dev/sandbox env to have a look at the development… — Sorry, so many questions, but you've been very helpful!

Comment: (2b) They need to have basically admin privileges in the sandbox. Note that it only applies to the sandbox, so your prod data is safe. They do naturally need the ability to customize fields and objects, upload code, etc. (3b) The sandbox they develop in, or perhaps even better, a testing sandbox that you create for the purpose. The choice is yours.